# Javascript Preloading Images: Add to DOM, or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it necessary to add an `<img>` to the DOM in order to preload it?

```
$(function whenDOMIsHappy(){

  var $img = $('<img />')
    .load(loadHandler)
    .error(errorHandler)
    .attr({src:"squatchordle-squashgarden.jpg"});

  $img.appendTo('body .preloads'); // is this at all necessary?

});
// assuming <div class="preloads" style="display:none;"></div> exists in <body>.
```

I've seen mixed messages about this technique. I'm using jQuery, but the question applies to vanilla-people too.

I am interested in keeping this working in all major browsers.

Comment: As far as I know, yes, but I don't see the problem with it. Execute the script *after* dom ready and the client will not notice a thing.

Comment: what is in `loadHandler`?

Comment: @BramVanroy: I should have clarified: I'd prefer to avoid adding elements to the DOM if I don't have to.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Does it matter? I haven't gotten so far yet :) -- I just want to know how to preload an image properly, without knowing what I'll do once I've succeeded.

Comment: I imagine objections to this technique come from concern that this is an abuse of HTML, which -- in a perfect world -- should be used to describe the layout of the page. By adding an invisible `<div>` solely for image preloading, you've added structural markup that does not contribute to the content or meaningful semantic structure of the page. (I don't know enough about it to agree or disagree strongly with that viewpoint.) However, doesn't your first chain of jQuery (building the `<img>` and setting its `src`) trigger a preload, even without adding it to the DOM?

Comment: @apsillers One does not need extra markup (in the above case it is necessary, but the images can simply be appended to the body as well, without any extra markup). When an image is "built" in jQuery (i.e. its HTML structure is specified-, the image itself is *not* loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All browsers I've tested *do* load images even if they're not in the DOM. You can test this with https://jsfiddle.net/84tu2s9p/.

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
img.onload = () => console.log("loaded");
img.onerror = err => console.error(err);
```

- Safari 13, 11.1, 10.1
- Edge 18
- Firefox 72, 70, 62
- Chrome 78, 71
- Opera 64
- IE11

(Not meant to be an exhaustive list. I just tried a variety of versions and browsers.)

There's also the new [`image.decode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) API that is intended for this use case of preloading images and avoids potential dropped frames when actually decoding the image to render it. Edge doesn't support it yet (Chromium-based Edge will though).

Given that HTML Canvas can use images without them being in the DOM, I think they *have* to load images.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

as opposed to creating and then appending elements to the dom, why not just initialize a new image in javascript, then set its source to your images URL.  this method should load your image without actually applying it to an element or rendering it on the dom - YET... take a peek:

```
someImageArray[0] = new Image();
someImageArray[0].src = "http://placehold.it/700x200/";
```

from here you are free to do what you wish with that image using javascript - render it directly in canvas or create an element out of it.  however you might not even have to do anything.  say if its already being referenced in other ajax based content.  provided the URL is identical, the browser should use the cached version to draw the dom.

hope this helps [here is a reference to a decent article about pre-loading](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) with a few more options...

Comment: using an array in the example assuming we will be looping through a larger amount of images to preload

Comment: I am very well aware that this can be done without jQuery, and without dirtying up the DOM (which is something I would quite like to avoid). I've read several articles on the matter, but they tend to give conflicting advice. Some hint at the idea that the image must be added to the DOM in order to load in all browsers, but I wonder if this is a modern concern (as opposed to IE6 or something). The question really is: ***Will the image preload correctly in all of today's major browsers if I don't add it to the DOM?***

Comment: Honestly, I was hoping somebody would have been in my shoes before, and would just *know* this already. That person hasn't come out of the woodwork yet, so it looks like I've got some testing to do. I'll let y'all know when I'm done and have the answer ;)

Comment: @ChaseMoskal One problem is that even the [HTML5 spec allows for either possibility](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element). It says that a "user agent that obtains images immediately" must immediately preload the data whenever the `src` property changes and fire a `load` event when done. However, it also says that "a user agent that obtains images on demand must update the image data of an img element *whenever it needs the image data*" (i.e., *not* immediately, which would preclude preloading).

Comment: Just lately, I've been looking into doing this without jQuery -- however -- I can't seem to find any good documentation on JavaScript's `img` API. Does anyone know where I should look for this? I've checked MDN, and a number of WHATWG and W3 specs -- but nobody seems to have anything to say about the how the relevant events, like error and abort, work on the img element. Could both abort and error fire? Or just one? I guess jQuery will do it for me...

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/image.shtml  has some docs from 2005 - trying to turn up something of more substance  & the MDN  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement  is rather light

Comment: @Joe: It's looking like, with some initial testing -- one does NOT need to add `<img>`s to the DOM for IE7 and up. I'll post an answer after more thorough tests.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no guarantee that Images will be preloaded** if you don't add it to the DOM! If you don't add it, the JavaScript Compiler can aggressively garbage collect the Image before it tries to load, because the element is not used at all.

This currently happens in firefox! There your images will not be preloaded if you don't add them to the DOM! - So be on the safe side and add them.

Comment: You just need to keep a global reference to the image, then it won't garbage collect, even if it is never added to the DOM. For example some javascript games load all their images with new Image() and the game only starts once they are all loaded, and they are never added to the DOM, just drawn on a canvas only after all onloads fired. Do window.myImage=new Image(); myImage.src="squatchordle-squashgarden.jpg";

Comment: @Curtis good find, you should add this as a new answer, since canvas functions were not as wifely used in 2015. If you just create an img-Node and set source, the browser may not load the image. Using the constructor Image may provide a different behavior :-)