# Why does a dynamically added image always have an offsetWidth of 0

Tags: javascript

I am adding an image via Javascript.

The image could be of any size and I'd like to get the size (width and height).

The issue is, the `offsetWidth` and `style.width` is always 0

Here is some code to replicate

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/56e/hibiscus-1393855.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(img);
const result = document.getElementById("result");

result.innerText = (img.offsetWidth + " " + img.style.width);
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

The above works. I am running what appears to be near identical code but, it always shows an offsetWidth of 0

[image]

How do I get the image width and height

Comment: The width and height won't be known until the browser actually gets the image content from the server.

Comment: You don't place `img` into DOM, than you can't calculate image size using JS.

Comment: Need a load event listener to get dimensions after it loads

Comment: @pavel Not really true. Can listen to load event outside dom

Comment: Sorry, that is my poor copy and paste job - trying to keep it concise.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to load to be able to get its actual size:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = img.offsetWidth;
});
img.src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/56e/hibiscus-1393855.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: I am guessing the `load` is asynchronous?

Comment: Exactly. You are just registering a callback for the moment the image is there.

Comment: Thank you. I honestly thought appendChild would be a blocking call! Clearly it isn't

Comment: No, wait. It is. If you check a line later if the element is there, you will immediately see it. However, you have to distinguish the html img-element and the src file that has to be loaded asynchronously. once it is there, the img-element changes its dimensions.

Comment: So... for clarity, the appendChild has actually 'nothing' to do with this (expect it adds it to the DOM). The setting of the src is what begins the loading process? I don't expect you to know the answer, but if I set the src and don't append it to the dom, would it still load the image :/

Comment: Yes, I think preoading the src before attaching it to the DOM is possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/58842841/302793